# ¿Como recuperar el estado de una Activity luego de cerrarla?

Tags: android

¿Como puede un boton en android Cambiar de estado  disponible y ocupado y tener memoria?

ejemplo si salgo de la aplicación o si la manejo en segundo plano  cuando vuelva a la pantalla principal recuerde su estado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si sales completamente de la aplicacion completamente y quieres que tu aplicacion conserve tu estado, esto naturalmente no es posible tu tienes que implementar en que Activity quieres iniciar despues de cerrar la aplicacion, ya que cuando se cierra la aplicacion, se destruye completamente.

En el caso de tenerla en segundo plano y cuando vuelva a la pantalla principal regrese a su estado, esto puede ocurrir normalmente pero tendrias que implementar una recuperacion de datos en caso de no encontrar algun valor ya que el sistema operativo podria reclamar memoria y eliminar los valores almacenados en variables estaticas, y en un caso extremo todo el proceso, que seria similar a cerrar completamente la aplicacion.

Para implementar que tu aplicacion conserve su estado tendrias que hacer uso de almacenamiento de datos el preferencias o base de datos.

Comment: Gracias  utilice Shared preference